# Xcode and Distribution .ipa application provisioning profiles

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, ipa

I lost few days trying to figure this out. I created new provisioning profile on my dev account for Ad Hoc distribution, I added required certificates. I did set everything to this profile in General tab and Build settings for both project and target, I'm not using Automatic signing. When I archive project I'm using diawi app to install .ipa file on my iPhone but I keep getting error that provisioning profile inside this app doesn't seem to contain your device's UDID.

Comment: Upload both ipa and provisional profile to diwai

Comment: issue fixed or not?

Comment: Provisional profile is already with ipa file, application is signed with distribution profile

Answer (score 1):

your provisioning profile must contain your device's UDID.

Comment: Could you expand a little more on how you do this for the user?  He or she probable knows how to read the error message but doesn't know what steps to take to fix it.

Comment: Yes for development what about distribution? How to do this for live application?